# android.net.TrafficStats missing functions

Tags: android, network-traffic

I would like to measure the traffic rate in Android with `android.net.TrafficStats`. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) says, there is a `getUidTcpTxBytes()` and a `getUidUdpTxBytes()` function in this class. These ware added in API level 8.
I'm using API level 8, but I can not find these functions, only some of them like `getTotalRxBytes()`.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getUidTcpTxBytes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidTcpTxBytes%28int%29) was added in API Level 12, as was [`getUidUdpTxBytes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidUdpTxBytes%28int%29). You can tell this by viewing the methods in the JavaDocs and seeing the "Added in API level 12" notation, on the right side of the gray bar that houses the method signature.

Comment: @yoman: The class was added in API Level 8. However, individual pieces of the class, like methods, can be added later.

Answer (score 0):

Look closer: [getUidTcpTxBytes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidTcpTxBytes%28int%29) was added in API Level 12, as well as getUidUdpTxBytes(). Actually most of them were added after API Level 12 and 14.